# what happened to the stack camera_pose in groovy?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I checked the package page for camera_pose stack and it seems that it should still exist in groovy. But when I am trying to install it from debian for Ubuntu 12.04, I cannot find any package named ros-groovy-camera-pose or anything similar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69655/what-happened-to-the-stack-camera_pose-in-groovy?/) by [Emma.lzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/4271/emma.lzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2013-09-05**:
I would also like to know this and can't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package seems to be deprecated and broken.  There seems to be a fork available at this location:
https://github.com/jbohren-forks/camera_pose

It seems to be compatible with groovy

---

Originally posted by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) with karma: 163 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0